# Trying to use smpclient() for sending mail to the user from my host

Tags: c#, smtp, webmail

its my first time to work smpclient() function in C# . 
I'm trying to send one simple mail to my E-mail address from my host webmail .

my details :

```
My website : www.chicardari.ir   
Source mail : info@chicardari.ir (from)  
Destination email : vbhost.ir@gmail.com (to)
title : title_Hello world body : body_Hello world
```

**my code.**

```
    protected void BtnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.chicardari.ir", 25);

        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@chicardari.ir", "Passwprd");
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //Setting From , To and CC
        mail.From = new MailAddress("info@chicardari.ir", "chikardari");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("vbhost.ir@gmail.com"));
        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("vbhost.ir@gmail.com"));

        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
```

**I used:**

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
```

after executing i face to this error :

```
 System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mail.chicardari.ir'
```

**note** : i dont know what is my host port and even how to get it . 
please help me emphasized text

Comment: Try using port 587. It's an alternate port for regular SMTP.

Comment: You can also try with telnet program and see if it can listen on this port.

Comment: Dont use SSL _Set smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;_

Comment: I really hope your password isn't actually `"Passwprd"`...

Comment: As it says, the host `mail.chicardari.ir` does not exist, connecting to `chicardari.ir` however elicits an smtp response.

Comment: If you ping mail.chicardari.ir what do you get?

Comment: @codebased How to try with that port ?

Comment: @BossRoss I did but still the same error .

Comment: @Okuma.Scott no thats not the correct password ...

Comment: SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.chicardari.ir", 587);

Comment: @Donal ping cant find it . I don't know 'mail.chicardari.ir ' is correct or not . my domain name is : www.chicardari.ir

Comment: @codebased Still the same error

Comment: @Arashbahreini ok, you need to speak to your hosting provider and ask them the details of their SMTP service.

Comment: The port number is irrelevant if the host does not resolve. Try `new SmtpClient("chicardari.ir", 25);`

Comment: @ Alex K After it i got this error : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 164.138.23.42:25

Answer (score 0):

Got it mate.

By using this tool I can see it is connecting

http://www.adminkit.net/smtp.aspx

Connecting to mail server.
Connected.
220 WIN-T2D6ANG73NS.sabasystems.ir ESMTP MailEnable Service, Version: 8.04-- ready at 09/09/14 16:04:27
EHLO Server01
250-sabasystems.ir [64.85.165.1], this server offers 4 extensions
250-AUTH LOGIN
250-SIZE 5120000
250-HELP
250 AUTH=LOGIN
RSET
250 Requested mail action okay, completed
MAIL FROM: 
250 Requested mail action okay, completed
RCPT TO: 
503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.

SMTP protocol error. 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server..Forcing disconnection from SMTP server.
QUIT
221 Service closing transmission channel
Disconnected.

SMTP session Takes 1.9500034  Seconds

if you replace your host from mail.chicardari.ir to chicardari.ir it will work.

```
 protected void BtnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("chicardari.ir", 25);

        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@chicardari.ir", "Passwprd");
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //Setting From , To and CC
        mail.From = new MailAddress("info@chicardari.ir", "chikardari");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("vbhost.ir@gmail.com"));
        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("vbhost.ir@gmail.com"));

        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }
```

If still it does not work then speak to your service provider.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you but i got this error :A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 164.138.23.42:25

Comment: Best is to contact, you will save lots of time.